# GTK applications looking bad

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, gtk3

I'm running ArchLinux and gnome shell 3.16.1. 
GTK+ theme: Evopop-gtk-theme
Icons: Adwaita
Global dark theme.

Running applications like nautilus, gnome-tweak-tool, dconf, system-monitor, gnome-terminal I get the style I have configured.

The problem is when I run other applications like Filezilla, Thunderbird, Caja, Terminator, Eclipse, Wireshark ... Then I get an old style looking  and I don't know what is happening. If I run other window manager like awesome-wm or i3 I get a default adwaita style in all applications.

Let me show you an example:
[image]

And here is some basic config:

**/home/n/.config/gtk-3.0**
*settings.ini*

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

*gtk.css*

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

**/home/n/.config/gtk-2.0**
empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Adwaita GTK theme is for both GTK3 and GTK2, but the theme you installed (Evopop-gtk-theme) seems to work only for GTK3. So that's why GTK2 applications look ugly.

The way to fix it is to install lxappearance (or any other GTK2 config tool, but this one is lightweight and has no dependencies) and set GTK2 theme to something similar to your current GTK3 theme.

Comment: This helped me. Finally I decided to change the theme for GTK 2 and 3. I chose Libra instead of Evopop.